# Efficiently parallelising independent tasks

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, processing-efficiency

I have [;N;] work units, [;w_n;], which are effectively embarrassingly parallelizable. Each takes approximately a given length of time, [;t_n;], which we know in advance.

Given that I need may need to process some subset of the work-units, and a constraint that I may use a maximum of [;P;] processes, each on separate CPUs, how do I efficiently distribute work-units, in advance, to processes such that all processes finish as close to each other (in time) as possible?

Answer (score 2):

A) If they are all statistically the same duration, and you have no control over how long any one of them runs, I'd guess on average you can't do any better than "a processor on finishing a work unit, takes any unfinished work unit and executes it till completion".  Your average runtime will be Sum(1..N,t_n)/P.

B) If they had somewhat predictable times, I'd be tempted to ask each process to pick the remaining work unit with the longest-estimated time, and run that.  This runs all the expensive work first, leaving lots of little jobs to backfill the remaining time.

C) If you insist on a static schedule chosen in advance, run algorithm B) offline
and preassign the work units in order to the processes.  That's likely to give you longer total runtimes than a dynamic schedule, which can take the actual variation into account somewhat.

Comment: I have updated the question. We have an idea of how long each of the work-units takes to run (and the expectation is not equal). The work units to be processed must be allocated to process in advance of beginning computation.

Comment: *Must* be allocated? Are you sure this is a requirement? If it is, you'll pick a static schedule first and have to live with the consequences.  That's likely to give you longer total runtimes than a dynamic schedule, which can take the actual variation into account somewhat.  Is that the tradeoff you want to make?  If not, my B) answer is probably the best.

Comment: The use case is slightly unusual but I think it means that our allocation of tasks must be in advance. We are applying many transformations to data contained in a large blob (a zip containing hundreds of thousands of xml files). Each task (transformation) is applied to every xml file and output is written sequentially to a set of output files, one for each transformation. By allocating as we do, we avoid any issue of thread-safety since there are no shared resources apart from the input file (read-only).

Comment: Each transformation adds a given length of time to the process however we do not know which subset of transformations are required in advance, or how many cores we will be allocated.

Comment: If you don't know how many cores you are going to be allocated, how can you possibly define a schedule in advance? (I suppose you could decide you had a max of M cores, and simply build M schedules one for 1 cpu, one for 2,... one for M, and choose the right one at the first execution moment when you find out how many CPUs you do have).

Comment: If every work-unit processes an XML file and writes a files specific tot that, how can you have a resource contention problem?   If that's not the case, where in your "advance" scheduling did you take the resource contention into account?  You didn't ask about this aspect, but it will surely have a huge impact on the chosen schedule.  And, if you do have a shared resource problem, you can still solve that at runtime with locks or some such. I doubt the execution costs of the locks will have any impact, although the delays they induce could have serious impact.

Comment: You have another resource contention problem: reading the individual files.  Presumably the zip file is huge; thus scattered to some degree all over the disk. You ideally don't want to access the disk randomly to read it, yet a schedule based on runtime and nothing is likely to do just that.  You now want your schedule to include apparant time to access the next file; where will you get that data?.  You have similar troubles for *writing* the replacement files; the OS isn't likely to cooperate and write them sequentially.  I think you're going to need several strategies to try, and measure :-}

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to get back to this. At present the method for each process could be expressed as: `for xml in xmlFiles: for (tname,transform) in transforms_allocated: outputfile[tname].write(transform(xml))`. The work units aren't processed sequentially on each process but rather run sequentially on each file.

Comment: I think you're right though, we will need to test several strategies to balance the costs of reading and processing.